# warning is :pages have non-alpha characters in their description meta tags

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, tags, meta-tags

I have implemented a Multi-Language website with asp.net MVC, some analysers find a warning in some languages which it has special characters like french language. 
the warning is this

> some of your pages have non-alpha characters in their description meta tags

how I should correct this ? Appreciate any help or knowledge.

Comment: What kind of analysers? Do you have an example for such a `meta`-`description`?

Comment: @unor thank you for your care, it seems I found what is the problem, it can not reconize some characters like this `ä` and I tried to use html entities for these characters but still have some errors on it

Comment: @unor I asked another new question.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51685721/while-using-html-entities-it-also-translate-ampersand?noredirect=1#comment90333471_51685721 . I am using godaddy analyzer