# While using HTML entities, it also translates ampersand &

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, html-entities

I am working on a ASP.NET MVC multi language web site.

When I put for example `&#233;` to achieve this `é`, it changes it to `&amp;#233;`.

It seems that it first translates `&` to `&amp;`.

What is the problem?

Comment: Try `@Html.Raw("&#233")`

Comment: thank you very very much I checked it still nothing changed. any other idea? @StephenMuecke

Comment: There could be a number of reasons why this is occurring, however I would try changing the character set of the document in it's head first to see if that resolves it.  Add <meta charset="utf-8" /> to the head (see here for explanation - https://www.w3schools.com/TAGs/att_meta_charset.asp) and see if it works.  If it does not work post some of your code so we can help.

Comment: @garrettlynch there is this code in the head of my website `<meta charset="utf-8">` should I change it?

Comment: @neda Derakhshesh ok so you're not really helping us help you.  If you had posted a link to your site or your code I could have checked that.  You can try removing the meta tag to see if it helps but we really need to see more.  Post a link to the page or edit your question and post the page's code.

Comment: Where are you getting that HTML entity from, how are you encoding it (note that you do *not* need to encode it). Please add those details to your question

Comment: @neda Derakhshesh your page has the correct meta tag <meta charset="utf-8"> to render the French alphabet.  I've looked at your site and everything looks correct.  I've also looked it up in google and it displays correctly - where are you seeing this displayed incorrectly?  As I said before you need to add more detail to your question by editing it and including your code, a screenshot of what you are seeing would also help and then describe the problem more fully.  However, everything looks correct to me.

Comment: @garrettlynch thank you very very very much. 100...00 times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I think I might see what you are referring to.  In the meta tags in the head of your document `&#233;` is changing to `&amp;#233;` but the entities in the body are correct.

You have perhaps copied and pasted é from a rich text environment (i.e. an rtf or perhaps a .doc file) and it may contain an encoded ampersand rather than a plain text ampersand.  Rule of thumb - never ever ever copy text from something like word as it copies across all sorts of invisible characters.  When you prepare copy for your website always do in in plain text (.txt) files and you'll know your text is clean.  If a client gives you .doc file convert them to .txt first and you will see any issues before you copy them into the html.

However, in the head of your document when you have text in an attribute value, what's between the quotes, for example in the content attribute of the description meta tag, like so:

```
<meta name="description" content="Enregistreur vocal est une application polyvalente avec un son de haute qualité." />
```

you don't need to use entities because that string is plain text not html - so change it to a normal é and it should work.

**Note:**  The above assumes that the string in the meta tags are not coming from a database but is actually in the html page.  If the string is coming from a database and then placed into the meta tags you may have used something like HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlEncode() in asp to place it in the database in the first place - that's the root of the issue.  If this is the case, before you place it in the meta tag you need to use HttpContext.Current.Server.Htmldecode() to convert it back to plain text.

Comment: thank you very much, helpful knowledge . appreciate very much. but just a question. I wonder to know why google does not recognise my descriptions? I used view bag to consider my description for each page

Comment: @neda Derakhshesh it looked correct in Google when I checked it but I suspect that Google treats meta description tags as plain text only.  Perhaps those on Stackoverflow who are search engine optimisation specialists could confirm this?  Anyway hope its working for you now :)